# Get shopping cart details in Magento2

Tags: magento2

I know in Magento 1 you can get the shopping cart details on any page with:

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $productId = $item->getProduct()->getId();
    $productPrice = $item->getProduct()->getPrice();
}
```

How do I do the same thing in Magento 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured this out by myself in the end:

```
<?php

$om =   \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cartData = $om->create('Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
$cartDataCount = count( $cartData );

?>
<div class="bagDrop" id="bagDrop">
    <h4><a href="<?php echo $block->getShoppingCartUrl(); ?>">Quote Basket</a></h4>
    <?php if( $cartDataCount > 1 ): ?>
        <a href="#" class="arr up off" id="bagDropScrollUp"></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="bagDropWindow">
    <?php if( $cartDataCount > 0 ): ?>
        <div class="bagDropList" id="bagDropList">
            <?php foreach( $cartData as $item ): ?>
                <?php $product = $item->getProduct(); ?>
                <?php $image = $product['small_image'] == '' ? '/pub/static/frontend/Clear/usb2u/en_GB/images/default-category-image_1.png' : '/pub/media/catalog/product' . $product['small_image']; ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $product['request_path']; ?>" class="bagDropListItem">
                    <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>">
                    <p>
                        <span class="name"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></span><br>
                        <span class="qty">x <?php echo $item->getQty(); ?></span>
                    </p>
                </a>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <div class="emptyList">No products in your basket.</div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <?php if( $cartDataCount > 1 ): ?>
        <a href="#" class="arr dn" id="bagDropScrollDown"></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 19):

```
protected $_checkoutSession;

public function __construct (
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $_checkoutSession
    ) {
    $this->_checkoutSession = $_checkoutSession;
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
  $cartData = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
  $cartDataCount = count( $cartData );
}
```

you can get the quote data in observer

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. No direct instantiation of ObjectManager, and logic not in a template.

Comment: Sir how can we get the Cart data on Homepage?? On homepage I'm getting *null array* while on cart page when I run the code it returns me the cart product... While I want these products on my Homepage

Answer (score 1):

Get Product Details in Checkout Page

```
 <?php
    namespace namespace\modulename\Block\xxx;

    class xxx extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {
        public function __construct(
             \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
             \namespace\modulename\Model\CrossSellFactory $crosssell,
             \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
             \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
             \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
             array $data = []
        ) {
             parent::__construct($context, $data);
             $this->cart = $cart;
             $this->_crosssell = $crosssell;
             $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
             $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        }
        public function getProductIds()
        {
             $productInfo = $this->cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
             foreach ($productInfo as $item) {
                 $item[] = $item->getProductId();
                 echo"<pre>";print_r($item->getProductId());
             }
                 return $item;
        } 
    }
```

Put the above .php file in your block and return the value in phtml file like i shown below.

```
    <?php
    $Productdetails = $block->getProductIds();
    echo"<pre>";print_r($Productdetails->getName());
    ?>
```

Comment: Use this code for to get product details in checkout page in magento2

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score -2):

Usage examples:

1. [`\Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\AbstractCart::getQuote()`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/958164/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Block/Cart/AbstractCart.php#L101-L112):

   ```php
   /**
    * Get active quote
    *
    * @return Quote
    */
   public function getQuote()
   {
       if (null === $this->_quote) {
           $this->_quote = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote();
       }
       return $this->_quote;
   }
   ```
2. [`\Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Totals::getQuote()`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/958164/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Block/Cart/Totals.php#L190-L205):

   ```php
   /**
     * Get active or custom quote
     *
     * @return \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote
     */
   public function getQuote()
   {
       if ($this->getCustomQuote()) {
           return $this->getCustomQuote();
       }

       if (null === $this->_quote) {
           $this->_quote = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote();
       }
       return $this->_quote;
   }
   ```
3. [`\Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart::getQuote()`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/958164/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Helper/Cart.php#L146-L155):

   ```php
   /**
    * Retrieve current quote instance
    *
    * @return \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote
    * @codeCoverageIgnore
    */
   public function getQuote()
   {
       return $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote();
   }
   ```

Answer (score -2):

You can easily get the shopping cart details in the Magento 2 by implementing the below-mentioned code:

```
<?php
$object =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $object->create('Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
$cartCount = count( $cart );
if($cartCount > 0){
    echo $cartCount;
    } else{
        echo "0" ;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: It returns 0 although I have items in cart